# Не работают списки доступа

Tags: cisco

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Списки доступа вообще не работают, ни одна из правил. Ни доступ к серверу, ни передача пакетов, даже сайта не открывает. Я думаю у меня проблемы с активацией списка доступа ? Ну или вообще не знаю. Пинги проходят и имеют к доступу лишь к серверу которые находятся в одной сети с пк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас правила 20,30 в acl 170 срабатывают первыми запрещая трафик. До правил 40,50 не доходит проверка.
При составлении acl , указывайте в начале более специфичные правила, например разрешайте/запрещайте по портам, а затем уже более общие, хосты, подсети.

Например, первое правило разрешает http трафик между хостами, второе запрещает остальное. В конце acl, по умолчанию, deny any any, помните об этом.

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли понять свою ошибку, как то не подумал о таком. Впредь буду внимательнее.